# Looker Data Studio is triggering multiple duplicated queries to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

It's a very weird issue.

I have a dashboard, actually multiple dashboards in Looker Data Studio that pull data from different tables in BigQuery. BigQuery only. No GA4 or any other types of connectors. BigQuery billing is set up.

I've started seeing quota error and after certain investigation I found out that one dashboard refresh creates around 200 queries with only 7 unique SQLs.
Means that Looker Data Studio sends the same query around 20 times.

I don't know whether it leads to the quota error or it's something else but this query multiplication seems to be weird.

What could be the reason of such behaviour?